# How to add multitouch support for ChromeEmbeddedFramework browser on windows 8?

Tags: python, windows-8, multi-touch, chromium-embedded

I 've develooped a basic custom browser with CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) Python . This browser is meant to run into an interactive kiosk with windows 8. It has a multi-touch screen for all user interactions.

If I run Google Chrome on the machine, the multi-touch gestures (scroll and virtual keyboard) are supported.

Unfortunately my CEF browser doesn't have detect any multi-touch event. How can I fix it? ANy pointer is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by using CEF3 rather than CEF1